# PyTorch: How to sample from a tensor where each value in the tensor has a different likelihood of being selected?

Tags: python, random, pytorch, probability, sampling

Given tensor
`A = torch.tensor([0.0316, 0.2338, 0.2338, 0.2338, 0.0316, 0.0316, 0.0860, 0.0316, 0.0860])` containing probabilities which sum to 1 (I removed some decimals but it's safe to assume it'll always sum to 1), I want to sample a value from `A` where the value itself is the likelihood of getting sampled. For instance, the likelihood of sampling `0.0316` from `A` is `0.0316`. The output of the value sampled should still be a tensor.

I tried using `WeightedRandomSampler` but it doesn't allow the value selected to be a tensor anymore, instead it detaches.

One caveat that makes this tricky is that I want to also know the index of the sampled value as it appears in the tensor. That is, say I sample `0.2338`, I want to know if it's index `1`, `2` or `3` of tensor `A`.

Comment: why not convert it as tensor after sampling?

Comment: I'm using it for training and don't want to lose the gradient computation.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Actually I rounded to the fourth decimal place for this post but it's safe to assume the values will be summing to 1. I like your solution. Why should `A.cumsum(0)` be precomputed if used multiple times?

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff - It's the computationally most intensive part and likely doesn't change each time.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Could you add this as an answer?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Also, I'm interested in knowing the index of the value returned. So in the example above say it returns `0.2338` I would like to know is it index 1, 2 or 3. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selecting with the expected probabilities can be achieved by accumulating the weights and selecting the insertion index of a random float [0,1). The example array *A* is slightly adjusted to sum up to 1.

```py
import torch

A = torch.tensor([0.0316, 0.2338, 0.2338, 0.2338, 0.0316, 0.0316, 0.0860, 0.0316, 0.0862], requires_grad=True)

p = A.cumsum(0)
#tensor([0.0316, 0.2654, 0.4992, 0.7330, 0.7646, 0.7962, 0.8822, 0.9138, 1.0000], grad_fn=<CumsumBackward0>))

idx = torch.searchsorted(p, torch.rand(1))
A[idx], idx
```

Output

```
(tensor([0.2338], grad_fn=<IndexBackward0>), tensor([3]))
```

This is faster than the more common approach with `A.multinomial(1)`.
Sampling 10000 times one element to check that the distribution conforms to the probabilities

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(int(A.multinomial(1)) for _ in range(10000))
#1 loop, best of 5: 233 ms per loop

# vs @HatemAli's solution
dist=torch.distributions.categorical.Categorical(probs=A)
Counter(int(dist.sample()) for _ in range(10000))
# 10 loops, best of 5: 107 ms per loop

Counter(int(torch.searchsorted(p, torch.rand(1))) for _ in range(10000))
# 10 loops, best of 5: 53.2 ms per loop
```

Output

```
Counter({0: 319,
         1: 2360,
         2: 2321,
         3: 2319,
         4: 330,
         5: 299,
         6: 903,
         7: 298,
         8: 851})
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
probs = torch.tensor([0.0316, 0.2338, 0.2338, 0.2338, 0.0316, 0.0316, 0.0860, 0.0316, 0.0860],requires_grad=True)

dist=torch.distributions.categorical.Categorical(probs=probs)
probs[dist.sample()]
```

Comment: Nice approach! I added a benchmark of this solution to my answer.

Comment: This is the best one!

Answer (score 1):

the solution from the accepted answer (by Michael Szczesny) can be expanded to cover 2d tensors with probabilities, like softmax of model outputs. Just adjust the dimensions of the random tensor accordingly.

```
def multisample_from_softmax(softmax_values):
    """
    quick weighted sampling using pytorch
    softmax_values : torch.tensor shaped (n_tokens, embedding_vocab_size)
    returns: torch.tensor shaped(n_tokens) with indices of sampled tokens
    """
    size = softmax_values.shape[0]
    rand_values = torch.rand((size, 1), device=softmax_values.device)
    cumprobs = softmax_values.cumsum(dim=1)
    selection = torch.searchsorted(cumprobs, rand_values).squeeze(1)
    selection_probs = (softmax_values[:, selection] * torch.eye(size, device=softmax_values.device)).diagonal()
    return selection, selection_probs
```

Answer (score -1):

You can cheat a little by doing something like this:

```
A = A*10000
temp = [[i]*A[i] for i in range(len(A))]
value = np.random.choice(temp)/10000
```